# XML сериализация/десириализация

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть такой XML:

```
<Config>
 <Fields>
  <Field>F1</Field>
  <Field>F2</Field>
 </Fields>
</Config>
```

Можно ли заставить этот XML работать не с таким классом:

```
public class Config
{
    [XmlArray("Fields")]
    public List<Field> Fields;
}
```

А вот с таким:

```
public class Config
{
    [XmlArray("Fields")]
    public List<string> Fields;
}
```

Т.е без создания дополнительного класса.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать необходимые атрибуты. Вы уже поставили `[XmlArray("Fields")]`, так поставьте и для имени такой же - `[XmlArrayItem("Field")]`.

То есть класс будет следующий:

```
public class Config
{
    [XmlArray("Fields")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
    public List<string> Fields;
}
```

Кстати, если не ошибаюсь, то `[XmlArray("Fields")]` тут и вовсе избыточен, ибо у вас и так коллекция и имеет имя `Fields`.